# How to find the address belongs to the kernel

Tags: linux, insert, linux-kernel, object-address

I need to find the address of kernel for a testing, I want to insert some code from the 1394 fireware to the kernel, but I don't know how to find the address belongs to the kernel? Thanks a lot

Comment: This doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not very clear what you want to do, do you want to inject code in the kernel from your application? (Thanks God) You can't.

Comment: @Adriano Is that the case even for kernel-mode code? Can kernel modify itself?

Comment: @zxcdw I was talking about _applications_. Yes, to modify the kernel from the kernel itself is possible (http://kerneltrap.org/node/395) even if I'm not sure if Linux applies the same protection for self-modifying code to kernel code too. The (subtle?) question was "do you want inject code in the kernel from firewire?", don't break security in that way...

Comment: @Adriano OHCI 1394 adapters will, as far as I know, let other 1394 devices write to arbitrary *physical* memory locations, unless the system is using an IOMMU. The *virtual* memory protections therefore have no effect on such DMA. So hot-patching code that way is almost certainly feasible, though doing so safely will require some cooperation from the kernel.

Comment: @pmjordan you're right, I assumed memory protection for code was available for all processors but it's absolutely not true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd start by looking at [Documentation/debugging-via-ohci1394.txt](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/debugging-via-ohci1394.txt). It's possible to debug the kernel via Firewire, so presumably it's also possible to inject code that way.

Would you care to explain what you're trying to accomplish? Just about the only things I can think of are Evil.

Comment: I am doing a test for the function of Intel VT-d, this is what I am studying.